# Adding linear function coefficients to the title of a plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I am solving a task for my R online course. The task is to create a plot, as identical as possible to the following:

[image: Goal-Plot]

The plot is to be tested with 80 observations by given random number functions and set.seed(1423). The code looks like this:

```
Reg<-function(Anzahl){
  set.seed(1423)
  if(Anzahl<0|!(is.numeric(Anzahl)&&floor(Anzahl)==Anzahl))stop("Schreiben Sie eine positive ganze Zahl")
  X<-runif(Anzahl,min=0,max=20)
  Y<-3-0.2*X+rnorm(Anzahl,0,1)
  plot(X,Y,axes=F,xlab=NA,ylab=NA,cex=0.8,pch=24,bg="darkblue")
  axis(side=1,at=c(0,5,10,15,20),col=NA,cex.axis=1.2)
  axis(side=2,at=c(-2,0,2,4),col=NA,las=1,cex.axis=1.2)
  mtext(side=1,"Unabhängige Variable",line=2,cex=1.1)
  mtext(side=2,"Abhängige Variable",line=2,cex=1.1)
  abline(lm(Y~X),col="red",lwd=2)
  grid()
}
Reg(80)
```

And produces the following plot:

[image: Created plot]

I have two questions:

1) how can I change the title of the plot to show the coefficients in the way they are shown in the first plot?

2) is there a way to force an axis to show only even numbers (this is also part of the task, in the code I've defined the y-axis to contain -2, 0, 2, 4, but can I generalize that I want only even numbers for the y-axis?

Any other recommendations to make the plot as identical as possible are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:

```
Reg <- function(Anzahl) {
  set.seed(1423)
  if (Anzahl < 0 | !(is.numeric(Anzahl) && floor(Anzahl) == Anzahl)) {
    stop("Schreiben Sie eine positive ganze Zahl")
  }
  X <- runif(Anzahl, min = 0, max = 20)
  Y <- 3 - 0.2 * X + rnorm(Anzahl, 0, 1)
  plot(X, Y, axes = F, xlab = NA, ylab = NA, cex = 0.8, pch = 24, bg = "darkblue")
  axis(side = 1, at = unique(round(X)[round(X) %% 5 == 0]), col = NA, cex.axis = 1.2)
  axis(side = 2, at = unique(round(Y)[round(Y) %% 2 == 0]), col = NA, las = 1, cex.axis = 1.2)
  mtext(side = 3, font = 2, cex = 1.1, 
        text = "Regressionanalyse \n Gleichung: y(x)= 2.89 -0.21 x")
  mtext(side = 1, "Unabhängige Variable", line = 2, cex = 1.1)
  mtext(side = 2, "Abhängige Variable", line = 2, cex = 1.1)
  abline(lm(Y ~ X), col = "red", lwd = 2)
  grid()
}
Reg(80)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for little automated version, then you can try below logic:

**Logic**

1) To capture the regression equation: I have a equation model, then capture the coefficient using coef function and paste it on the heading.

2) To automatically use the sequence on y axis, I have used the floor and ceiling function w.r.t Y axis.

**Note**: Due to differnt local settings I am unable to get (ä) character properly rendered on my output. To deal with this I have used, `stri_trans_general` from `stringi`, package, you can totally avoid this step if your locale settings allow you to render these character.

```
    Reg<-function(Anzahl){
    set.seed(1423)
    if(Anzahl<0|!(is.numeric(Anzahl)&&floor(Anzahl)==Anzahl))stop("Schreiben Sie eine positive ganze Zahl")
    X<-runif(Anzahl,min=0,max=20)
    Y<-3-0.2*X+rnorm(Anzahl,0,1)
    ymin <- ifelse(min(Y) < 0 , floor(min(Y)), ceiling(min(Y)))
    ymax <- ifelse(min(Y) > 0 , ceiling(max(Y)), floor(max(Y)))

    model <- lm(Y ~ X, data = data.frame(X = X, Y=Y))
    object <- paste0('Y(x) = ', round(coef(model)[[2]],2), '*X', ' + ', 
                     round(coef(model)[[1]],2)) ##This is the object that should be pasted in main
    plot(X,Y,axes=F,xlab=NA,ylab=NA,cex=0.8,pch=24,bg="darkblue", 
         main=paste0("Regression Analysis \n",object)) #You can add any text here, note the new line in case you want something in next line.
    axis(side=1,at=c(0,5,10,15,20),col=NA,cex.axis=1.2)
    axis(side=2, at=c(seq(((ymin %% 2) == 0)*min(ymin) + ((ymin %% 2) != 0)*(ymin-1), 
                          ((ymax %% 2) == 0)*max(ymax) + ((ymax %% 2) != 0)*(ymax+1), 2)), 
         col=NA, las=1, cex.axis=1.2) # does not work
    mtext(side=1,stringi::stri_trans_general("Unabhängige Variable","zh"),line=2,cex=1.1)
    mtext(side=2,stringi::stri_trans_general("Abhängige Variable","zh"),line=2,cex=1.1)
    abline(lm(Y~X),col="red",lwd=2)
    grid()
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make the values of the x-axis fixed - when seed is changed sometimes not all of the values are shown and I want the values 0, 5, 10, 15, 20 to always be on the plot?